# How filter and sort in a nested tree Array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I need to filter and sort a nested tree object for menu

so is sort and filter status === true ,How to turn to

```js
const items = [{
    name: "a1",
    id: 1,
    sort: 1,
    status: true,
    children: [{
      name: "a2",
      id: 2,
      sort: 1,
      status: true,
      children: [{
          name: "a3",
          id: 3,
          sort: 2,
          status: true,
        },
        {
          name: "a5",
          id: 4,
          sort: 1,
          status: true,
        }
      ]
    }]
  },
  {
    name: "b2",
    id: 2,
    sort: 2,
    status: true,
    children: [{
        name: "a2",
        sort: 1,
        status: false,
        id: 2,
        children: [{
          name: "a3",
          id: 3,
          sort: 1,
          status: true,
        }]
      },
      {
        name: "a4",
        id: 8,
        sort: 2,
        status: true,
      }
    ]
  }
];

console.log('items:', items)
```

---

```
const items = [{
    name: "a1",
    id: 1,
    sort: 1,
    status: true,
    children: [{
      name: "a2",
      id: 2,
      sort: 1,
      status: true,
      children: [{
          name: "a5",
          id: 4,
          sort: 1,
          status: true,
        },
        {
          name: "a3",
          id: 3,
          sort: 2,
          status: true,
        }
      ]
    }]
  },
  {
    name: "b2",
    id: 2,
    sort: 2,
    status: true,
    children: [{
      name: "a4",
      id: 8,
      sort: 2,
      status: true,
    }]
  }
];
```

Comment: You are moving something from b2 to a1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write two recursive functions:

- One to filter out the `status: false` items
- One to sort items by their `sort` property

You can combine the two in any order you like.

### `itemFilter`

The `filter` function takes a list of items. It goes over each of them and checks if it has `children`. If so, it filters those first. Then, it discards all items with `status: false`.

### `itemSorter`

The `sort` function is very similar. It goes over each item and checks if there are children. If so, it sorts those first. Then, it sorts the list it was passed.

```js
const itemFilter = items => items
  .map(item => item.children 
    ? { ...item, children: itemFilter(item.children) }
    : item
  )
  .filter(item => item.status);
  
const itemSorter = items => items
  .map(item => item.children
    ? { ...item, children: itemSorter(item.children) }
    : item
  )
  .sort((i1, i2) => i1.sort - i2.sort);
  
  
const items=[{name:"a1",id:1,sort:1,status:true,children:[{name:"a2",id:2,sort:1,status:true,children:[{name:"a3",id:3,sort:2,status:true},{name:"a5",id:4,sort:1,status:true}]}]},{name:"b2",id:2,sort:2,status:true,children:[{name:"a2",sort:1,status:false,id:2,children:[{name:"a3",id:3,sort:1,status:true}]},{name:"a4",id:8,sort:2,status:true}]}];


console.log(
  itemSorter(itemFilter(items))
);
```

Comment: Thank you, it took me a lot of time for this logic, thank you very much